# Xcode: How to add a file to a folder reference

Tags: xcode

I want to add a file to an existing folder in Xcode. I have a folder in the file system that I have added to my resources. Now when I add a file to that folder, and try to drag and drop that file onto the folder reference in Xcode, I am out of luck.

Even if I delete the reference and drag the whole folder over again, it does not work, as it imports all files that were in the folder when I originally imported it, but not the new ones.

Any ideas on that one?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drag it into that folder in Finder, then right click that blue folder in Xcode and then "touch" it. Or collapse and expand that folder icon (is like touching it).

Comment: A note here: If you are using git, the files that you add this way will not be added to git, you'll need to add those manually (I just used `git add`)

Comment: Do you mean if you are using Xcode for version control?  I ignore Xcode's functionality for this and use the much more powerful SourceTree, so that's not a problem.